# Can Windows 7 be installed on an extended partition?

Tags: windows-7, installation, multi-boot, partitioning

I think on my notebook computer, it has one primary partition of 160GB with Vista on it and another primary partition of 83GB, and this is divided into 2 extended partition -- one is 67GB and one is 16GB.  And 2 Ubuntu installations are on these 2 partitions.

So after I deleted the 67GB partition, I wanted to go ahead and install Windows 7 on it (Update: so it will boot Vista, Ubuntu, and Win7), but Win 7 seems to want to install in the whole 83GB partition (and says the 83GB partition is "unallocated").

So must I do that -- can I installed Win 7 on the 67GB partition or must I install it on the whole primary partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problem installing to a 67GB partition. Just start the Win 7 upgrade installer and choose custom, than install it to that partition that you chose.

Comment: I agree with AskaGamer